# python socket.accept() abstracted socket type

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a program with multiple sockets using a select statement to manage them using the following code :

```
while not self.stopped:
        input_ready, output_ready, except_ready = select.select(self.input_sockets, [], [], 5)
        if (not input_ready) and (not output_ready) and (not except_ready):
            print("Timed Out")
        else:
            for s in input_ready:
                s.process_data()
```

For this to work I have created a class which is abstracted from `socket.socket` and adds the method `process_data`. I have a class defined this way, which binds to a socket to listen for inbound connections and when `process_data()` is called, it accepts the connection using `(sock, address) = self.accept()` ... I then add `sock` to the `input_sockets` array for use in the select, but obviously the accept method returns a socket, not an abstracted class with and therefore has no `process_data()` method, so this causes errors.

Can anyone think of a way that I could use the `accept()` method to return my own abstracted socket class rather than a normal socket?

Thanks

EDIT :

I have found a happy work around for now - Instead of creating an abstracted socket class, I have created a standard class as follows:

```
class DirectConnection():

  def __init__(self, sock):
    self.socket = sock

  def fileno(self):
    return self.socket.fileno()

  def process_data(self):
    print("Got data")
```

Then from my listening socket

```
(sock, address) = self.accept()
socketmanager.monitor_socket(DirectConnection(sock))
```

The `select.select` makes use of the fileno property of the socket object, so by defining a `fileno()` method which returns the `fileno()` of the socket passed into the class, I can now have the `select.select` call my method on this class, which I can then instruct to send/receive data from the socket passed in.

credit goes to : http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/437702-subclassing-socket and http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52295/

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do what you want exactly. You have to use delegation instead of inheritance, which means passing in your socket object into an instance of your own class, and then overriding `__getattr__()` and `__setattr__()` to effectively pass most method/attribute calls to your class onto the socket object. This covers the general idea: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52295/

Comment: :) I've just been looking at the same link. I've edited my post to provide my work around. Thanks for helping out, it's my first couple of weeks with python so all help is appreciated.